# Rails: Meaning of "<entity>_params" in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hard time understanding this code:

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

What actually bothers me is the line `@article = Article.new(article_params)`.

It has the key-value pairs from the according web-formular. I have printed it to the console.

**But where does `article_params` come from?**

It hasn't been declared somewhere.

Comment: article_params will be defined in the controller under the private section. It's a method that determines what params are permitted and is generated automatically

Comment: @jamesc Indeed. If I scroll down to the bottom, then there it is. It's weird, that parenthesis for Ruby method-invocations are optional.

Comment: @jamesc If you like to turn your comment to an answer, then go ahead. I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Rails conventions, the `<entity>_params` is a method declared in the private section of the controller that returns [filtered parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) send with the request.